# Not Change URL in selenium chrome python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when I use get function in chrome selenium for first time it's ok but for second time get function doesn't look like update
example

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  ## For Maximam Windows##
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",
{"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

def fun1():
  brows.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
  print(brows.current_url)
```

when call fun2 the URL doesn't change

```
def fun2():
  brows.get("https://www.google.com/")
  print(brows.current_url)
```

when run function output of print in both function is https://www.facebook.com/

can anyone say what's problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  ## For Maximam Windows##
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",
{"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

def fun1():
  driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
  print(driver.current_url)

def fun2():
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  print(driver.current_url)

fun1()
fun2()
```

Results : [image]